# Function with generic type constraint vs function with reference to trait object. Why is one allowed and one not?

Tags: rust

Very wordy title, but basically my question is, why am I allowed to do this:

```
pub fn dot<T,K>(a: &K, b: &K) -> T where K: InnerProductSpace<T> { todo!() }
```

but not this:

```
pub fn dot<T>(a: &dyn InnerProductSpace<T>, b: &dyn InnerProductSpace<T>) -> T { todo!() }
```

The error for the latter is

```
the trait `geometry3d::InnerProductSpace` cannot be made into an object
the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized` rustc(E0038)
```

It returns the same error whether I used the `dyn` keyword or not, and whether I use `Box` or not. Why is the second way disallowed?

Comment: The first way uses generics, the second way uses trait objects, and `InnerProductSpace<T>` is not object safe. That's literally what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: The short answer is `InnerProductSpace` is not object-safe. A longer and more detailed answer can be found here https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/sizedness-in-rust.md#trait-objects